# Visual Studio 2013 and Github account authentication not working

Tags: git, visual-studio, authentication, github, visual-studio-2013

This has been racking my brain for the past 4 hours.   I've googled, watch videos, came here looking for a solution, but nothing.

So I am trying to setup Visual Studio 2013 with git, and specifically my Github account.

Everytime I try to push a change I get this error meessage:

"An error occurred. Detailed message: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Authorization Required)."

I have never gotten the prompt to input my credentials, so it's not an invalid username/password error.

The URL I use to either publish or clone is https://github.com/[github_username]/[repo].git

I installed the 3rd party tools.  I ensured that git is available from the command line.  I can clone a repo I created on Github.  Wincred is set as my credential helper.  When i manually do a git push from the command line, it correctly asks for my credentials once, and after that it uses the stored one, visible from the credential manager.

A guide that I used initially was this:

http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step

I'm really at a loss here on how to get visual studio to prompt me for the username or for that matter use the stored ones.  I'm sure it's some stupid setting I missed, or something I installed incorrectly.

Comment: Do you have 2FA activated on GitHub for your account? (https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/)

Comment: Did you installed (as in http://www.woodwardweb.com/git/setting_up_the.html) the git-credential-winstore? (http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @VonC Checked and i don't have 2FA enabled, that program comes pre-bundled with msysgit now.  However, I had already tried both ways.  The issue is that VS is not prompting me at all.  Just immediately fails.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT]** The problem with not being prompted for credentials boils down to Visual Studio storing your user names and passwords for your GitHub accounts in the [Credentials Manager](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon), a.k.a. the Windows vault. You can edit credentials stored in the vault, or you can remove the related entry all together. The latter will cause Visual Studio to again prompt you for credentials the next time you try to sync with the remote on GitHub or whatever.

(If you don't tick the "remember" check-box in the prompt, nothing will be stored in the Credentials Manager.)

I'm leaving the rest of this answer as is for reference. On a side note: 2FA is a good thing.

---

I know you say you don't use two factor authentication, but a guy called [Kris van der Mast](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/default.aspx) wrote about this [in his blog](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/GithubAndVisualStudioAndTwoFactorAuthentication.aspx).

If in fact your problem in some way relates to what Kris writes about, then according to [Phil Haak](http://haacked.com/) the solution described [may be obsolete](http://haacked.com/archive/2015/04/30/github-in-your-visual-studio/) (at least if you go with Phil's suggestion to use the updated GitHub Extension for Visual Studio, as described).

I have the same problem as you describe, not even getting the prompt to enter credentials, and that may be a different issue (I also get a 403, not a 401 in the error message). Still, your error message is the same as Kris' and maybe reading about what he's doing helps in some way.

If I find a solution to the immediate problem of not being prompted, I'll update my answer accordingly.